# JQuery UI Datepicker's select Month/Year drop down doesn't work in iPad if the Datepicker is on JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-dialog

I have created a jQuery UI datepicker like this:

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: null,
            dateFormat: dateTimeFormat,
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: urlPath + 'Content/styles/images/calendar.gif',
            buttonText: 'Calendar'
        });

    $('input.datetime', controlContext).datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(inst, controlContext).val(dateText);
            var dateSelected = $(inst, controlContext).datepicker("getDate");
        },
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            $('.hasDatepicker').blur();
        }
    });
```

It works in all the major browsers. It works fine on Ipad also only if it is not on jQuery dialog. On jQuery dialog also if I use the datepicker for just selecting some date it is working fine. Only the dropdown for selecting some month or date is not working at all. I can see the dropdown options and even can click on any of the options but it is not hiding the option list after selecting any of the options, it just stays there.

After lot of debugging  I found out that the `onchange` event that is supposed to fire at the time of selecting any month or year is not firing.

To repeat again even selecting of month/year works fine on iPad, if the datepicker is not on jQuery dialog.

Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: could you post more relevant code, e.g. dropdown, and onchange? can you put them in jsfiddle?

Comment: are you using the latest JQuery UI? Is the dialog modal?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be something related to the ui-datepicker-div being created outside of the popup.  I was having the same issue while using twitter bootstrap modals.  I was able to get around it by using the following:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').ready(function() {
  var popup = document.getElementById('**ID OF YOUR POPUP**');
  var datePicker = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');
  popup.appendChild(datePicker);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that resolve the problem.  Now the datepicker is not correctly paced but at least it's working !

Comment: Indeed, same here; this solved the main problem. Any clue on how to fix the placement offset induced by the solution?

Comment: @mabian69 Can you get me a screen shot of what you are seeing and a code sample?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/mabian/kLdQm/
Month and year drop downs don't work in Firefox. One solution is moving the datepicker div and make it become a popup child, but this is a cumbersome solution because I have a JQuery Mobile app that is in fact a single page application, and the date picker control can be used inside or outside the popup.

Comment: Also, moving the datepicker inside the popup screws up the datepicker placement logic... thanks.

Comment: @mabian69 I have it working http://jsfiddle.net/Jadedcore/DdMRH/ in firefox and I corrected the placement offset. It appears that each time the assigned datePicker field gets focus, the styling of the datepicker div is created. The style is created with "position:absolute" which is causing it to display improperly. I added a focus event of my own on the input that re-styles the div to "position:fixed" which corrects the placement. You could style the div however you want from here. It is kind of a hacky solution, but it works for now.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. As you say, this is really fiddly, and needs the datepicker div to be moved here and there in reference to the container... which is not ideal imho...

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug reported: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8989 (it's marked as fixed but the discussion suggests it wasn't fixed properly).

I'm experiencing the issue on Bootstrap Modal with jQuery-UI date picker on Firefox/Mac.

Comment: I am having this issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this issue while working with a twitter-bootstrap modal; just like JadedCore, who answered above.  I fairly certain his assumption that the datepicker being created outside of the popup (in my case, the modal) was the cause of the problem.

I've used this datepicker in several modals and wanted something to 'fix' all locations.  I took JadedCore's answer and modified to be more universal for multiple modals; I also move the datepicker back to the body when a modal is closed.  I foresee issues with this example if there are multiple modals being displayed simultaneously, so beware.

```
$(function() {
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var datePicker = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');
        if (datePicker) {
            e.delegateTarget.appendChild(datePicker);
        }
    });

    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {      
        var datePicker = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');
        if (datePicker) {
            $("body").append(datePicker);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me: http://jsbin.com/onuhos

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution was simply to increase the z-index of the dataPicker owner element, in your case increase z-index of `$('input.datetime', controlContext)`