# JQuery UI datepicker dropdowns don't work on Firefox with JQuery Mobile popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I know there are many other similar posts but could not find one with this exact problem
(one on which I already posted is [JQuery UI Datepicker's select Month/Year drop down doesn't work in iPad if the Datepicker is on JQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283793/jquery-ui-datepickers-select-month-year-drop-down-doesnt-work-in-ipad-if-the-d))

A JQuery UI datepicker (1.10.3) put in a JQuery Mobile popup (1.3.1) has month and year dropdowns not working, at least in Firefox (currently on V25).

Example here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mabian/kLdQm/
```

If I move the datepicker div inside the popup with something like this

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').ready(function () {
    var popup = document.getElementById('dialog-popup');
    var datePicker = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');
    popup.appendChild(datePicker);
});
```

it works, but datepicker placement is screwed and I would prefer avoiding to move inside and outside the div because I can have it also outside the popup in other places.
Is there anything that can be done to make it work (or at least fix the datepicker placement)?
Modifying the JQM file IS an option, I need to fix this and there's no plan to update the frameworks currently.

Thank you,
    Mario